# If $f$ is Lipschitz, $\phi$ is a solution of $x'=f(x)$, and $f(t,H(x))=DH(x)\cdot f(t,x)$ then $\phi(t,t_0,H(x))=H(\phi(t,t_0,x_0))$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to prove the next result on differential equations.

> Let $H:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^1$  and $f(t,x)$ a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(t,H(x))=DH(x)\cdot f(t,x)$ (and $D$ is the differential operator). If $f$ is Lipschitz  and $\phi(t,t_0,x_0)$ is a solution of $x'=f(x), x(t_0)=x_0$, then 
>   $$\phi(t,t_0,H(x))=H(\phi(t,t_0,x_0))$$

Here is my attempt:

\begin{eqnarray}
D[H(\phi(t,t_0,x_0))]&=&DH(x)\cdot \phi'(t,t_0,x_0)\\
&=&DH(x)\cdot f(t,x)\\
&=& f(t,H(x))\\
&=&D(\phi(t,t_0,H(x))
\end{eqnarray}
Is this correct? And, does this (together with the lipschitz  condition) imply the conclusion?